# How to export a table as a png file?

Tags: graph, stata

I have some data for which I need to inspect how variables change over time using the `tabulate` command. I also want to export the output as graphics files, for example `png`.

Below is some example data:

```
sysuse auto
tab rep78 turn
```

However, the `graph export` command is not working, since there is no graph output.

Is there a way to do this in Stata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have installed [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) on your computer and you have also configured it *correctly*, you could first export the table in a log file. Next, you can import the table as string and manipulate it to include the instructions for ImageMagick and export this again. Finally you simply run the `shell` command to perform the conversion.

Reproducible example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
quietly log using mytable1.txt, text replace
tabulate rep78 turn
quietly log close

preserve
clear
set obs 3

generate strL text = ""
replace text = `"text 0,0 ""' in 1
replace text = fileread("mytable1.txt") in 2
replace text = subinstr(text[2], "quietly log close", `"""', .) in 2

generate new = filewrite("mytable2.txt", text, 2)
restore

! source .bash_profile && convert -size 800x600 xc:white -font "CourierNew" ///
  -pointsize 12 -fill black -draw @mytable2.txt mytable.png
```

Result:

[image]